# Room: Proper way to test DAO Apis

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing

I just went through the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db) for testing the room dao in android.

There's a method listed on that page:

```
@Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun writeUserAndReadInList() {
        val user: User = TestUtil.createUser(3).apply {
            setName("george")
        }
        userDao.insert(user)
        val byName = userDao.findUsersByName("george")
        assertThat(byName.get(0), equalTo(user))
    }
```

I've a doubt here.

Doesn't it violate the principle of junit testing that each method should be tested in isolation.

Here, we are testing both write and read. If the test fails, we don't know which api is buggy - the one which writes or the one which reads.

I think if we want to test the read api. of dao, write should directly be done using `SQLiteOpenHelper` so that it's guarranteed to insert an item and our test just tests the read api.

Same for the case when we want to test write api.

Answer (score 1):

You could always insert whatever object you are testing against in the init method, like so:

```
@Before
fun createDb() {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context, TestDatabase::class.java).build()
    userDao = db.getUserDao()
    val user: User = TestUtil.createUser(3).apply {
        setName("george")
    }
    userDao.insert(user)
}
```

That way you can write smaller tests that focus on reading only.